# Find number of times recognized audio repeat in the source

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft, audio-fingerprinting

I want to find the number of times a snippet of audio is repeated in another audio.
There are libraries like https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu which can be used to create fingerprints of audio after that it can be used for recognition but it only tells whether the snippet exists in audio or not, it does not give count.

Is there any way to make changes to find the number of times the recorded audio repeats in the source(any audio from database)?

Thanks

Comment: seems like it would be fun to write your own audio fingerprinting algo then simply iterate across all audio samples in your source audio and send just the current windows of audio samples into that algo then slide this window of samples forward in time and repeat ... no ?

Comment: It's strange it does not give you count. I am pretty sure if you forked the package you could fix this easily. Best make an issue in dejavu github and this question there

Comment: @dankal444 I did make an issue on dejavu github.

Comment: @ScottStensland Wouldn't be time-consuming? I have quite a big source audios(2-3 hours), and there may be many matched sources from the database that would create a problem. I was thinking of finding a repeating pattern in the Source audio once dejavu confirmed that snippet audio exists in the source audio... before that need to study signal processing.

Comment: audio fingerprinting is a vast topic no wonder Apple paid $400 million to buy Shazam ... read https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15809291   ... driven from the number of audio samples in your snippet you pluck same number of audio samples from the source audio and perform a match check then slide that window of samples along the source and repeat ... for a given window you do a FFT call and drive the match from comparing FFT of snippet to current window ... this is as simple as possible and yes its resource intensive

Comment: if you think this would be time-consuming I challenge you to do a deep dive into video transmission using say H.265 right down to the pixel level as it gets transported using network packets + payloads ...  only to realize those video codec are only feasible because that algo is baked into hardware

Comment: @ScottStensland thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an exact copy, you may want to convolve said audio with the source audio you're trying to extract from. Then the peaks from the convolution will show you where the offset is.

Answer (score 0):

One could use the approach and Python code detailed in [How to find out how many times a specific audio repeats in another longer audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75961430/how-to-find-out-how-many-times-a-specific-audio-repeats-in-another-longer-audio/75990628) to get a list of matches for query in a specific file. Then run this for each file in the database, and then count up the number of matches.