# How to find out how many times a specific audio repeats in another longer audio?

Tags: python, librosa, audio-fingerprinting

I have an example of an audio ad and a recording of a radio stream. I want to find out how many times this specific ad repeats in this stream. Tried to use audio fingerprinting and librosa library. But my command seems to run forever, I've already waited for 30 minutes and it is still running. Can you please say what is wrong with my code? How can I optimize it?

```
import numpy as np
import librosa

def count_repeats(ref_file, longer_file):
    # Load the reference and longer audio signals
    ref_audio, ref_sr = librosa.load(ref_file, sr=None, mono=True)
    longer_audio, longer_sr = librosa.load(longer_file, sr=None, mono=True)

    # Compute the cross-correlation between the reference and longer audio signals
    corr = np.correlate(ref_audio, longer_audio, mode='full')

    # Find the time lag that maximizes the cross-correlation
    lag = np.argmax(corr) - len(ref_audio) + 1

    # Compute the duration of the reference and longer audio signals
    ref_duration = len(ref_audio) / ref_sr
    longer_duration = len(longer_audio) / longer_sr

    # Compute the number of repeats based on the time lag and the duration of the audio signals
    repeats = int(np.floor((longer_duration - lag) / ref_duration))

    return repeats

ref_file = 'house_ad.mp3'
longer_file = 'long_audio.mp3'
repeats = count_repeats(ref_file, longer_file)
print(f'Number of repeats: {repeats}')
```

Comment: did you try debugging the code where it is taking too much time or which line causing the problem?

Comment: Indeed, "debug and profile" is the answer to almost every "too long" or "too slow" question.

Comment: Can you upload an audio clip of the advertisement and one of a section of radio?

Comment: @JonNordby ad clip (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YLscgtfq8OQ9CyASNYkQX4qvPX046rn2/view?usp=share_link)
long audio (https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Z3_4gL1aRWvUf7TiuE6ldaDat7rMMzb/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Thanks. In that clip, is it correct that the ad only appears at minute 3 and 51?

Comment: @JonNordby, it appears 3 times, two that you mentioned and also at minute 38

Comment: Right, thanks. I will write up an answer with a solution that finds those, probably later today :)

Comment: @JonNordby omg, that would be extreeeemely helpful:)

Comment: Answer provided now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your function is very slow probably that cross correlation is a O(n**2) operation, and with audio sample-rates n is very large. With a 60 second and a 60 minute, it is an estimated 105*10e12 operations.

And while cross-correlation is conceptually a valid approach for comparing a signal against a template it is quite fragile - as even the tiniest change in the audio will throw it off.

A much more robust and also more computationally efficient approach is to do matching in another feature space. For audio a good starting point may be [MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum).

A basic but very effective method of signal matching is described in
[DiagonalMatching](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/C7/C7S2_DiagonalMatching.html) from the book [Fundamentals of Music Processing
Using Python and Jupyter Notebooks](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/fau/professor/mueller/bookFMP) (FMP) by Meinard Müller.

Below follows complete code following this method. On your example, it manages to successfully identify the 3 locations of the provided clip at the correct locations.

NOTE: This approach assumes that the audio clip being queried for is very similar each time it appears.
But if there is considerable variation in the clip, or it or occurs together with other sounds et.c, more advanced approaches will be needed.

The complete notebook can also be found [here](https://github.com/jonnor/machinehearing/blob/master/handson/advertisement-detection/AudioMatching.ipynb).

```py
import math

import numpy
import pandas
import librosa

import seaborn
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np = numpy # code from FMP uses this

def normalize_feature_sequence(X, norm='2', threshold=0.0001, v=None):
    """Normalizes the columns of a feature sequence

    Notebook: C3/C3S1_FeatureNormalization.ipynb

    Args:
        X (np.ndarray): Feature sequence
        norm (str): The norm to be applied. '1', '2', 'max' or 'z' (Default value = '2')
        threshold (float): An threshold below which the vector ``v`` used instead of normalization
            (Default value = 0.0001)
        v (float): Used instead of normalization below ``threshold``. If None, uses unit vector for given norm
            (Default value = None)

    Returns:
        X_norm (np.ndarray): Normalized feature sequence
    """
    assert norm in ['1', '2', 'max', 'z']

    K, N = X.shape
    X_norm = np.zeros((K, N))

    if norm == '2':
        if v is None:
            v = np.ones(K, dtype=np.float64) / np.sqrt(K)
        for n in range(N):
            s = np.sqrt(np.sum(X[:, n] ** 2))
            if s > threshold:
                X_norm[:, n] = X[:, n] / s
            else:
                X_norm[:, n] = v
    else:
        raise ValueError("Norm type not supported")

    return X_norm

def compute_features(audio, sr, hop_length=512, n_mfcc=13, n_fft=None):
    
    if n_fft is None:
        n_fft = next_power_of_2(hop_length)
    
    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length, n_mfcc=n_mfcc)
    # Normalize using Euclidean norm - as the diagonal matching code expects it
    mfcc = normalize_feature_sequence(mfcc)
    
    return mfcc


def cost_matrix_dot(X, Y):
    """Computes cost matrix via dot product

    Notebook: C7/C7S2_DiagonalMatching.ipynb

    Args:
        X (np.ndarray): First sequence (K x N matrix)
        Y (np.ndarray): Second sequence (K x M matrix)

    Returns:
        C (np.ndarray): Cost matrix
    """
    return 1 - np.dot(X.T, Y)

def matching_function_diag(C, cyclic=False):
    """Computes diagonal matching function

    Notebook: C7/C7S2_DiagonalMatching.ipynb

    Args:
        C (np.ndarray): Cost matrix
        cyclic (bool): If "True" then matching is done cyclically (Default value = False)

    Returns:
        Delta (np.ndarray): Matching function
    """
    N, M = C.shape
    assert N <= M, "N <= M is required"
    Delta = C[0, :]
    for n in range(1, N):
        Delta = Delta + np.roll(C[n, :], -n)
    Delta = Delta / N
    if cyclic is False:
        Delta[M-N+1:M] = np.inf
    return Delta

def mininma_from_matching_function(Delta, rho=2, tau=0.2, num=None):
    """Derives local minima positions of matching function in an iterative fashion

    Notebook: C7/C7S2_DiagonalMatching.ipynb

    Args:
        Delta (np.ndarray): Matching function
        rho (int): Parameter to exclude neighborhood of a matching position for subsequent matches (Default value = 2)
        tau (float): Threshold for maximum Delta value allowed for matches (Default value = 0.2)
        num (int): Maximum number of matches (Default value = None)

    Returns:
        pos (np.ndarray): Array of local minima
    """
    Delta_tmp = numpy.array(Delta).copy()
    M = len(Delta)
    pos = []
    num_pos = 0
    rho = int(rho)
    if num is None:
        num = M
    while num_pos < num and np.sum(Delta_tmp < tau) > 0:
        m = np.argmin(Delta_tmp)
        #print(Delta_tmp.shape)
        #print('argmin', m, Delta_tmp[int(m)])
        pos.append(m)
        num_pos += 1
        # exclude this region from candidate minimums
        s = max(0, m - rho)
        e = min(m + rho, M)
        #print(s, e)
        Delta_tmp[s:e] = np.inf
    pos = np.array(pos).astype(int)
    return pos

def next_power_of_2(x):
    return 2**(math.ceil(math.log(x, 2)))

def plot_results(scores, threshold=None, events=None):
        
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(30, 5))
    ax.plot(scores.reset_index()['time'], scores['distance'])

    if threshold is not None:
        ax.axhline(threshold, ls='--', alpha=0.5, color='black')
        
    if events is not None:
        for idx, e in events.iterrows():
            ax.axvspan(e['start'], e['end'], color='green', alpha=0.5)
    
    import matplotlib.ticker
    x_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(ticker_format_minutes_seconds)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_formatter)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=10*60))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=60))
    ax.grid(axis='x')
    ax.grid(axis='x', which='minor')

    return fig
    
def ticker_format_minutes_seconds(x, pos):
    hours = int(x//3600)
    minutes = int((x%3600)//60)
    seconds = int(x%60)

    return "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)


def find_audio(long, short, sr=16000, time_resolution=0.500, max_matches=10, score_threshold=0.1):

    # distance between frames in feature representation [seconds]

    hop_length = int(time_resolution*samplerate)
    
    # compute features for the audio
    query = compute_features(short, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length)
    clip = compute_features(long, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length)
    

    # Compute cost matrix and matching function
    C = cost_matrix_dot(query, clip)
    Delta = matching_function_diag(C)
    
    scores = pandas.DataFrame({
        'time': librosa.times_like(Delta, hop_length=hop_length, sr=samplerate),
        'distance': Delta,
    }).set_index('time')
    
    # convert to discrete
    match_idx = mininma_from_matching_function(scores['distance'].values,
                                               num=max_matches, rho=query.shape[1], tau=score_threshold)

    matches = scores.reset_index().loc[match_idx]
    matches = matches.rename(columns={'time': 'start'})
    matches['end'] = matches['start'] + (query.shape[1] * time_resolution)
    matches = matches.reset_index()
    
    return scores, matches
```

Here is how to use it

```py
# configuration
samplerate = 16000
threshold = 0.02
max_matches = 3 

short, sr = librosa.load('house_ad.m4a', sr=samplerate)
long, sr = librosa.load('long_audio.m4a', sr=samplerate)

scores, matches = find_audio(long, short, max_matches=max_matches, score_threshold=threshold)

# print results
for idx, m in matches.iterrows():
    td = pandas.Timedelta(m['start'], unit='s').round('1s').to_pytimedelta()
    print(f'match {idx}: {td}')

# visualize results
fig = plot_results(scores, events=matches, threshold=threshold)
fig.savefig('results.png')
```

It should output

```
match 0: 0:38:26
match 1: 0:03:47
match 2: 0:51:35
```

and give a plot like this.
[image]

Comment: I aprecciate your help so much!!!  and also the literature you recommended. I will certainly have to deepen my knowledge about audio-processing because it is smth that I'm going to use so frequently in my work.

Comment: You are welcome. I have seen many variations on this question being asked on SO, and never really had a good answer. Now there is at least one :)

Comment: can you please explain possible rho for following:
s = max(0, m - rho)
        e = min(m + rho, M)
        #print(s, e)
        Delta_tmp[s:e] = np.inf

Comment: Also, please let me know what is the intuition of considering threshold value 0.02?